# Differential equations proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone provide any hints or help for the following proof?

Show that every function $u$ given by $u=f(x^2+y^2)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function of one variable having a continuous derivative, is a solution of $yu_x − xu_y = 0$.

Kind regards

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}2x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
u'_x= f'(x^2+y^2)\cdot 2x,\quad u'_y=f'(x^2+y^2)\cdot 2y
$$
$$
yu'_x= xu'_y= 2xyf'(x^2+y^2)
$$